# Using () for calling a function with no parameters

Tags: elixir

What's a convention for using or ommitting parentheses when calling a function which accepts no parameters?

```
function1(aaa) |> function2() |> function3() |> function4(bbb)

# or

function1(aaa) |> function2 |> function3 |> function4(bbb)
```

Comment: If the arity is more than 1 it's ambiguous, but if not, I'm not sure I see a problem with it.

Comment: @AndrewLi, **What's a convention**

Answer (score 4):

I believe, there is no *convention* on it yet.

#### Pro

- `Elixir` compiler warns about calling functions without parentheses outside of chains.
- There is a risk to override a method call without parentheses with a local variable.

_

```
defmodule A do
  def a, do: "¡Yay!"
  def b1, do: IO.puts a
  def b2 do
    a = ":("
    # 100 LOCs
    IO.puts a
  end
end

iex> A.b1
"¡Yay!"
iex> A.b2
":("
```

#### Contra

- [`Credo`](https://github.com/rrrene/credo/blob/2c51773767fb4438403c4a6fac7422bbeba99c51/lib/credo/check/readability/no_parentheses_when_zero_arity.ex#L48) code analysis tool would report zero-arity function calls with parentheses by default.
- `Elixir` code itself does not seem to use parentheses.
- Aesthetics.

#### Conclusion

In my humble opinion, the rule of thumb “use parentheses when calling functions” has very little advantages, and global suppressing of `credo`’s guard does not worth it. I personally do not use them, unless it improves the readability. Hope it helps.

Comment: I might add one thought--calling a function that has no arguments with () makes it a bit more obvious that it's a function and not a value.  On the other hand since this is Elixir -- function vs. value is not so much of a concern anyway.